# What the meaning of " Unsupported expression" in Xunit test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit.net

I try to write my first xUnit test in .net core3.
I created a Repository interface and class implementation of the repository that all repositories derived from it.
I created a test project where I try to test an implemented repository.

Here is the repository test class:

```
public class RepositoriesTests
{
    private Mock<InternalDataRepository> _repositoryInternalMock;

    public RepositoriesTests()
    {
        //Mock immitates functiuonality of the object
        _repositoryInternalMock = new Mock<InternalDataRepository>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ShouldReturnPhoneNum() {

            _repositoryInternalMock.Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync());
    }
}
```

And here is InternalDataRepository defenition:

```
public class InternalDataRepository : Repository<Internal>, IInternalDataRepository
{

}
```

And Repository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<T> GetAsync(int id);
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync();
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    Task AddAsync(T entity);
    Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities);

    void Remove(T entity);
    void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);

    Task<int> SaveAsync();
}
```

But when i run test on RepositoriesTests object on this row:

```
_repositoryInternalMock.Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync());
```

I get this error:

```
 System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.GetAllAsync()
```

Any Idea why the test is failing? Why do I get an Unsupported expression error?

Comment: You should mock the interface (i.e. `Mock<IRepository<Internal>>`), not the class. Or make the method virtual